# FindMaximum error (not a real number)

Tags: warning-messages, maximum

For the code below, I get several error messages once I click the "Enable Dynamics" button. However, once I run the code, the output works fine, so, if that is all I wished to do, I would just live with the error. The problem is that I cannot get it to work fine when I save the output as a .cdf file, which I would like to do. So, I assume the ideal solution is to somehow get rid of the error messages altogether.

I have searched through this website and found a few answers to errors associated with FindMaximum, but the solutions are too complicated for my extremely minimal knowledge with Mathematica. If somebody knows a solution, I would be grateful.

Here is the code:

```
    c = 1;
Manipulate[
 max1 = x /. 
   Last[FindMaximum[{(0.8 + x/(0.1 + (0.8*x))) - (0.8 + (c*x)), 
      0 <= x <= 1.6}, {x, 0}]];
 max2 = x /. 
   Last[FindMaximum[{(0.8 + x/(0.1 + (A*x))) - (0.8 + (c*x)), 
      0 <= x <= 1.6}, {x, 0}]];
 Labeled[Show[{Plot[{{0.8 + x/(0.1 + (0.8*x))}, {0.8 + 
        x/(0.1 + (A*x))}, {0.8 + (c*x)}}, {x, 0, 1.6}, 
     PlotRange -> {0, 2.4}, AspectRatio -> 1.50, 
     Ticks -> {{{max1, 
         "E", {(0.8 + (max1)/(0.1 + (0.8*(max1))))/1.6, 0}}, {max1, 
         "E", {(0.8 + (max1)/(0.1 + (A*(max1))))/1.6, 0}}, {max2, 
         "R", {(0.8 + (max2)/(0.1 + (A*(max2))))/1.6, 
          0}}}, {{(0.8 + (max1)/(0.1 + (0.8*(max1)))), 
         "E", {(max1)/1.7, 0}}, {(0.8 + (max1)/(0.1 + (A*(max1)))), 
         "A", {(max1)/1.7, 0}}, {(0.8 + (max2)/(0.1 + (A*(max2)))), 
         "R", {(max2)/1.7, 0}}, {0.8, "     ", {1, 0.02}}}}], 
    Plot[{{(x/(0.1 + (0.8*x))) - (c*x)}, {(x/(0.1 + (A*x))) - (c*
          x)}}, {x, 0, 1.6}, PlotRange -> {0, 2.4}, 
     AspectRatio -> 
      1.5]}], {"Benefit-Cost              Benefit or Cost    ", 
   "Effort"}, {Left, Bottom}, 
  RotateLabel -> 
   True], "ENVIRONMENTAL FEEDBACK MODEL\n\nNATURAL SITUATION\n\nGreen \
Line: Cost function\n\nBlue Line: Expected benefit (top) or net \
benefit (bottom) function\n\nRed Line: Actual benefit (top) or net \
benefit (bottom) function\n\nR: Response to feedback\n", {{A, 1.2, 
   "A: Actual"}, 1.2, 0.6}]
```

Comment: Have you tried to isolate a minimal example? At least the error messages should be shown in the question.

Comment: I couldn't get the error. your code works perfectly.

Comment: Szabolcs, as neither a mathematician nor an expert in Mathematica, I do not understand what you mean by "isolate a minimal example." As for the error message, there are often several, but here is a copy of the first: "FindMaximum::nrnum: The function value 0. +0.00999999 c-0.00999999/(0.1 +0.00999999 E$$) is not a real number at {x} = {0.00999999}."

Comment: Xminer, that's interesting. I just updated my version of Mathematica to the latest, and I still get the error. Are you able to generate a functional CDF version?